# i tried to register netshell.dll failed in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, local-area-network

I cannot open my localconnection's properties, so I tried to register the netshell.dll file, but got a `dllregisterserver failed, return code is 0x80020009` error. When I used `regsvr32 netshell.dll /u`, it worked. After that, I use `regsvr32 netshell.dll` again, got that `dllregisterserver failed, return code is 0x80020009` error again, somebody help!

Comment: Try running command prompt as administrator. Also, use full path with quotes to see if that helps.

Comment: @peter same error. ps:since xp seems has no run as admin option, I use administrator to run the full path quote command.

Comment: i reinstall the os.